# Android Google address autocomplete PendingResult awaits forever

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-geocoding-api

Me and my project teammates are trying to get an address to autocomplete using the google API for android.
So far we're trying to test it with one word without worrying yet of adding a listener to the autoCompleteView. Anyway, we can't make our first test work.
Our GoogleAPIClient is set like this:

```
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

We have a connection listener, which is like this:

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    new GetPredictions().execute("boulevard");
}
```

And, finally (well, not finally, but this is as far as our code goes before being blocked in await), our AsyncTask class GetPredictions has a doInBackground method which is like this:

```
    @Override
     protected AutocompletePredictionBuffer doInBackground(String... test) {

        LatLng sudOuestLyon = new LatLng(45.708931, 4.745801);
        LatLng nordEstLyon = new LatLng(45.805918, 4.924447);
        LatLngBounds rectangleLyon = new LatLngBounds(sudOuestLyon, nordEstLyon);

        PendingResult<AutocompletePredictionBuffer> results  =
                Places.GeoDataApi.getAutocompletePredictions(mGoogleApiClient, test[0],
                        rectangleLyon, null);
        AutocompletePredictionBuffer autocompletePredictions = results
                .await();

        return autocompletePredictions;
    }
```

After debugging, we see that we are stuck in "await" (and the time-limited version times out). We tried giving it some time (a few minutes) but the app doesn't get past this method. The research zone (rectangleLyon) is a rectangle which covers the city of Lyon, France, and some of the surroundings. This is not so big a zone, and there aren't too much boulevards, so we'd think that a search for "boulevard" in it would return a result pretty quickly. We suspect that our GoogleApiClient might not be configured right, but it can connect, since we pass in the method that is called only through OnConnected, and a bad request wouldn't have returned the PendingResult in the first place, right?

Why this code stucks in `results.await()`?

Comment: I think you can first try the official sample for `google map autocomplete` [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places/tree/master/PlaceComplete) to see how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after more search, the problem was the automatic line in the manifest to declare key. Key declaration need to have "            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" and not the name originally in there.